# PHP database connectivity considerations

Tags: php, database, pdo, odbc

I am writing a new application in PHP which will be released to the public as a commercial application.  Up to this point, my experience has been with MySQL databases within PHP.

The end user is responsible for providing the database functionality and the PHP application will simply connect to it and use it.

My question is, as I do not know what database the user will be using, what way do I go about supporting this in PHP?

The questions I have are:

- Is ODBC the right way?  I refer to ODBC below but if ODBC is not the right method to use, the same questions apply for whatever is the suggested method.
- Do I lose any functionality/features using ODBC functions over the MySQL equivalents within PHP?
- Is there anything security related I need to keep in mind?  Eg I have used mysql_real_escape_string() in previous applications.  What is the ODBC equivalent (is it even needed?)
- I assume PHP can connect to a MySQL database using ODBC?  Does MySQL need configured in some way to allow this?
- Performance wise, is ODBC acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For support and performance, your best option would probably be PDO (PHP Database Object). This is core to PHP and supports all the main DB systems, will natively handle escaping strings and so on.

To stay agnostic, you can't use MySQL only things, e.g. LIMIT add that's not supported with all SQL databases.

But having said that, check first. If the client has a noSQL database, or uses Amazon with unique connection strings (for example) then you're in trouble.

Comment: I think PDO will cover most bases for me.  MySQL, PostgreSQL, Informix, ODBC, Oracle are all supported.  I found this tutorial on PDO useful http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, as I do not know what database the user will be using,
>   what way do I go about supporting this in PHP?

Here is a link to using Database Abstraction in PHP.

The purpose of a database abstraction library is to create uniformity in communicating with multiple database servers. Think of it this way, for your application to support multiple databases it would need different lines of code to perform the same functions on each.  With an abstraction library the application only needs one set of code to communicate with any database the library supports. This drastically increases the number of database server options available for your PHP application.

http://www.hosting.com/support/programming/using-adodb-to-build-a-database-agnostic-php-application

Comment: Please provide more explanation, and not just a link as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably standardize on PDO; it abstracts a good number of databases and exposes a unified interface, it's written in C and most people will have it installed by default.

Word of caution here; not all databases support the same SQL grammar, so you may have to provision for that as well. This is tricky though, but one way is to define a helper class in between PDO and your classes; this helper class would translate business logic calls into actual SQL. You could provide one that works for MySQL and let your users create the others? :)

Comment: @psynnott yeah, I believe Doctrine works around that problem ... but I'm sure it's not trivial :) btw, I've added to my point that PDO is written in C as opposed to ADODB. Point could be made that ADODB is pure PHP and therefore you'd have no dependencies, but PDO does come default in a lot of distributions :)